Get command line info of currently running Win 10 processes
I want to write a small java app (preferably Java 8) that does the following:

List all processes that are currently running in Windows 10 and find a specific one (name and PID, there can be multiple running instances of the same app!), e.g. notepad.exe
Read this process' command line, e.g. if you use notepad thisisatest in command prompt, then it opens a notepad window and the command line says notepad thisisatest in task manager.
If this info contains something specific, then I want to kill the process.

What I've already tested for 1. + 2.:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec as suggested here - it lists the notepad.exe process and its PID but there doesn't seem to be a way to also request the command line info
ProcessHandle as suggested here (Java 9+, tested with Java 11) - it finds the notepad.exe process but the command line info (process.info().commandLine()) is empty
jProcesses2 (Java 8, github), the first version was suggested here - this finds the right process but the info (process.command) is null

As for killing:

jProcesses2 provides an example on the github page (changePriority(), stop(), then kill()) but that doesn't work for some reason.
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /pid 1234 /f") (I got the PID with jProcesses2) works but I can't be sure that I'm killing the right process, unless I can also get the info somehow.

My question: 1. and 3. are working but how do I accomplish 2. (finding the command line info)?

I'm going to take you at your word as it looks like you've dug deeply into the support for displaying command line parameters. This is a little hacky but works for me, and you can get some ideas. My version of Powershell doesn't have options to control quoting of CSV but later versions do (q.v.)
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WinProcessExplorer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        record ProcInfo (String processId, String processName, String commandLine) {
            public ProcInfo(String[] tokens) {
                this(tokens[0],tokens[1],tokens[2]);
            }
        }
        final List<String> COMMAND = List.of(
                "powershell.exe",
                "Get-CimInstance",
                "-ClassName",
                "Win32_Process",
                "|",
                "Select-Object",
                "ProcessId,ProcessName,CommandLine",
                "|",
                "ConvertTo-Csv",
                "-Delimiter",
                "`t"
                );
        List<ProcInfo> allProcessInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(COMMAND).redirectError(Path.of(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "process-explorer-err.log").toFile()).start();
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(p.getInputStream())) {
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] tokens = s.nextLine().split("\t");
                if (tokens.length == 3) {
                    allProcessInfo.add(new ProcInfo(tokens));
                }
            }
        }
        allProcessInfo.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}


Thanks for the answer! What Java version is that? My Java 8 project doesn't recognize record. I found a way to get the command line info with WMIC, the list looks pretty good and it works but WMIC is apparently deprecated now.

You need java >= 16. 8 is pretty old ;)

Aha, just found this. It looks like my answer's version of the Powershell command would be Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name LIKE '%notepad%'" | Select name, ProcessId, CommandLine. The print looks pretty much the same, except that it actually respects the order of name,... The only downside is that you need Powershell (doesn't work with command prompt), which you have to install yourself.

Oh. I'm aware, I've only got Java 8 and 11 at the moment because of that licensing thing. It shouldn't be too hard to just omit that part and parse it by hand (like in my answer) but with the powershell command from your answer (hopefully). I'm going to test that when I'm back next week, thanks again! Can you still use taskkill /pid 1234 /f to delete the files in powershell?

Yes, or use Stop-Process. You can make the record into a regular class quite easily. I would have liked to use -UseQuotes Never but couldn't

Sorry about the delay! I'm currently testing powershell and it seems to be a bit finicky: For some reason it won't take the command as String (yes, ProcessBuilder takes Strings too) and throws an exception (CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified). No problem with a List though, as suggested by you (List.of is only available in Java 9+). No idea what the difference between new ProcessBuilder(command).start() and Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) is, they both work.

List.of is only a convenience, there are other ways of creating one, of course. Or you can use an array. The point is, the arguments to process creation are much better treated as separate tokens. For one thing, it helps with issues related to quoted parameters

Already had my fair share of problems with that, the filter requires some special care: While - Filter "name like '%notepad%'" works fine in PowerShell directly, in Java you have to do extra escaping (not just 1 backslash but 3): "-Filter \\\"name like '%notepad%'\\\"" (as list entry). No worries about the csv, there are going to be spaces in the command line info and I'm parsing it myself anyway. No idea how long WCIM will still work, so I'm going to add both versions (that and Powershell). Ad Stop-Process, is there no need for anything like /f (as with cmd's taskkill)?

No quoting necessary: "Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -like '*notepad*'}" is just one array (or List) element. Stop-Process does require -Force is that's what you want

I see, Where-Object replaces -Filter and you also need a vertical bar, so: ...Win32_Process | Where-Object.... Got it, thanks! I just came across another problem: PowerShell cuts off the command line text, you have to add | Out-String -Width 10000 right at the end (after Select-Object). I'm going to post the full command when I'm done.

I'd be surprised if anything is cut off when you're reading Powershell's output stream as opposed to viewing it in the terminal

The longest command line I'm currently using for testing is ~250 symbols (the real ones can be much longer than that) and it's not a problem with WMIC (command prompt and code - didn't find a command to change that either) but in PowerShell (both console and code) the default cut-off point seems to be only ~95 symbols.

The full command is: String[] commandList = { "powershell.exe","Get-CimInstance","-ClassName","Win32_Process","| Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -like '*"+appname+"*'}","|","Select-Object","ProcessId,ProcessName,CommandLine","| Out-String -Width 10000"}; Thanks for your help!

I found a way to get a filtered list, which also includes the command line info, with WMIC (docs):
Open two notepad instances with command prompt, e.g.:
notepad 1234 test and more and more and more text !!1!!!
notepad and againagainagainagain again

Afterwards the WMIC command
wmic process where "name like '%notepad%'" get name,processid,commandline

outputs:
CommandLine                                                Name         ProcessId
notepad  1234 test and more and more and more text !!1!!!  notepad.exe  22268
notepad  and againagainagainagain again                    notepad.exe  8396

Code to get the same list and close the processes using their PIDs in Java 8:
String myappname = notepad;

try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic process where \"name like '%%"+myappname+"%%'\" get name,processid,commandline");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    
    while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!line.trim().isEmpty() && !line.startsWith("CommandLine")) {
            String[] split = line.split("\\s+");

            if(split.length>3) {
                String[] split2 = new String[3];
                split2[1] = split[split.length-2]; //name
                split2[2] = split[split.length-1]; //PID
                String s = "";

                for(int i=0;i<split.length-2;i++) {
                    if(i!=0) { s += " "; }
                    s += split[i];
                }
                split2[0] = s; //command line info
                split = split2;
            }
            System.out.println("name='"+split[1]+"', PID="+split[2]+", info='"+split[0]+"'");

            boolean somecondition = true;
            if(somecondition) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /pid "+split[2]+" /f");
            }
        }
    }

    input.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

This prints:
name='notepad.exe', PID=22268, info='notepad 1234 test and more and more and more text !!1!!!'
name='notepad.exe', PID=8396, info='notepad and againagainagainagain again'

